# Problems when using the Central Limit Theorem in an approximation

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

Let's say the return on a hypothetical investment can take on three possibilities, all equally likely: $30\%$, $10\%$, and $-10\%$.  The expected value of the investment after n trials (assuming we started with $1) is:

$$ 
E[(1+i_1)(1+i_2)(1+i_3)\cdots(1+i_n)]
$$ 
Luckily, since the returns are all independent and identically distributed I can use the fact that the returns have zero covariance (and therefore $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$), so that the expectation can be written like so:

$$ 
E[1+i_1]\cdot E[1+i_2]\cdot E[1+i_3]\cdots E[1+i_n]
$$

$$
=(E[1+i])^n
$$

$$= (1.1)^n $$

(I used the fact that $E[1+i] = 1/3\cdot(1.3 + 1.1 + 0.9) = 1.1$.)

Nowhere did we use any approximation; the result is exact.

Now let’s do it another way.  Starting from back here:

$$ 
E[(1+i_1)(1+i_2)(1+i_3)\cdots(1+i_n)]
$$

We could change variables, where $1+i = e^δ$, (where $δ$ would be $\ln(1.3)$, $\ln(1.1)$, $\ln(0.9)$, each with $1/3$ probability).  Then we have:

$$
E[e^{δ_1}\cdot e^{δ_2}\cdot e^{δ_3}\cdots e^{δ_n}]
$$

$$ 
= E[e^{δ_1+δ_2+δ_3+\cdots+δ_n}]
$$

Now let us use the Central Limit Theorem.  If n is sufficiently large, then it would be reasonable to replace the exponent (i.e. $δ_1+δ_2+δ_3+\cdots+δ_n \approx n\mu $) with a normally distributed random variable, $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$ with

$µ = 1/3\cdot [\ln(1.3) + \ln(1.1) + \ln(0.9)] \approx 0.0841046$, and $σ^2 = 1/3 \cdot [(\ln(1.3)-µ)^2 + (\ln(1.1)-µ)^2 + (\ln(0.9)-µ)^2] \approx 0.0225997$.

Then we have:

$E[e^{N(nµ,nσ^2)}]$   (The expression inside the brackets is a lognormal random variable.)

$= e^{nµ + nσ^2/2}$   (This is the expectation of a lognormal random variable.)

$$
= (e^{µ + σ^2/2})^n
$$

If I plug in the values for $µ$ and $σ^2$, I get this:

$$ 
= (1.10010375)^n
$$

This is close to the actual answer of $(1.1)^n$ that we arrived at earlier, but here’s my problem: I would think that as n gets large, the true Expectation and the approximate expectation using the CLT should converge – after all, doesn’t the Central Limit Theorem say that the estimate only gets better the greater $n$ is?  However, you can clearly see that even though $1.1$ and $1.10010375$ are close, as they are raised to the nth power, and as $n$ gets larger and larger, their values diverge!

So what’s going on here??  I’ve either made a mistake or I am inappropriately using the CLT.

Any thoughts??

Comment: In short, you are using the CLT wrong.

Comment: I don't see how I made this particular mistake.  Had I made this mistake, then when evaluating the expectation $E[e^{N(nµ,nσ^2)}]$, I would have erroneously arrived at $e^{E[N(nµ,nσ^2)]} = e^{nµ}$.  Instead, I used $E[e^{N(nµ,nσ^2)}] = e^{nµ + nσ^2/2}$, which is the correct expectation for a lognormal random variable with parameters $nµ$ and $nσ^2$.  @AndréNicolas

Comment: Perhaps. Deleting comment.

Comment: @DirkGently, can you please elaborate on this?  I figure something is wrong with my use of the CLT but I can't precisely put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0):

The central limit theorem here implies that as $n\to\infty$,
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(\delta_i-\mu)\right)\to \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)\ \text{in distribution}.
$$
It does not say anything about the convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_i$ because it does not converge to anything. In particular, you cannot use it to say
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_i\to\mathcal N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)\ \text{in distribution}.$$

Comment: One can even mention that the limit the OP is interested in is dealt with by a so-called *large deviations principle*, not by a CLT.

Comment: Wait, doesn't the CLT say that given a sample of size $n$ (all independent and identically distributed), as $n$ gets larger, the distribution of the sample mean $\bar δ$ can be better and better approximated by a normal distribution with mean $µ$ and variance $σ^2/n$, where $µ$ and $σ^2$ are the population mean and variance, respectively?

And if this is true, then wouldn't this be true of *sum* of the sample values:

$
\sum_{i=1}^n δ_i = n\bar δ \sim N(nµ,nσ^2)
$

Comment: @Israel What do you have in mind when you state that $n\bar\delta\sim N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$? Please be specific since 1. this is not what the CLT says and 2. the object $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$ depends on $n$ hence this $\sim$ sign cannot refer to a limit in any classical sense.

Comment: @Did, when I say that $n \bar \delta\ \sim  N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$, I am saying that as n gets large, the distribution of $n \bar \delta$ looks more like a Normal Distribution with mean $n\mu$ and variance $n\sigma^2$.  The "$\sim$" over here means "has the probability distribution of".  This is a standard Normal approximation that works because of the CLT.

Comment: @Israel "This is a standard Normal approximation" Absolutely not. The approximation provided by the CLT is the *first* one in the answer above. Note furthermore that $\sim$ here *cannot* mean "has the probability distribution of" since the LHS may not be normal, for eny $n$.

Comment: *Typo: "for any $n$".

Comment: Do you agree with this source?:

http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/370/408clt.pdf

Specifically the 2nd paragraph entitled "Normal Approximation, Central Limit Theorem". (First bullet point.  I wasn't able to put an image in the comment.)

Comment: @Did In case you don't know which part I am referring to, if it helps, I will quote from the above source:


 "Normal Approximation, Central Limit Theorem
 
The Central Limit Theorem (CLT) says that the mean and the sum of a
random sample of a large enough size from an (essentially) arbitrary
distribution have approximately normal distribution: Given a random
sample $X_1,...,X_n$ with $\mu = E(X_i)$ and $\sigma^2 = Var(X_i)$, we have:


- The sample sum $S = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is approximately normal $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$."

Comment: The last formulation (approximately normal $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$) should be avoided at all cost and replaced by the rigorous fact that $(S_n-n\mu)/\sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,\sigma^2)$ (fact which is explicitely given in the source you linked to). A consequence of this kind of disregard for rigor is that you were naturally led to believe that $E(e^{S_n})\approx E(e^{n\mu+\sigma\sqrt{n} Z})=e^{n\mu+\sigma^2n/2}$ with $Z$ standard normal, for example in the sense that $\frac1n\log E(e^{S_n})\to\mu+\frac12\sigma^2$, which, except if the increments $X_i$ are normal, is wrong.

Comment: @Did, Ahh, I think I see what you are saying.  Tell me if I am correct:  The central limit theorem only makes claims about $(S_n-n\mu)/\sqrt{n}$ but not about $S_N$.  Therefore it is incorrect to make any statements about $S_N$.  So now I have another question: If we know the expectation of some random variable $\bar S$, then we also know that the expectation of this random variable multiplied by a constant $n$ is $E[n\bar S]=nE[\bar S]$.  So why does this argument fail when $\bar S$ is the average of a sample?

Comment: Which argument is supposed to fail, exactly?

Comment: @Did, let me ask it another way.  Where and exactly why does the following argument fail?

1. $(S_n-n\mu)/\sqrt{n} \to N(0,\sigma^2)$

2. $(S_n-n\mu)\to N(0,n\sigma^2)$

3. $S_n \to N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$

In going from 1. to 2., we are scaling $N(0,\sigma^2)$ to $N(0,n\sigma^2)$ and from 2. to 3., we are translating $N(0,n\sigma^2)$ to $N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$.

Comment: *Again*, in full generality, for some objects $x_n$ and $y_n$ depending on $n$, what is the meaning of $x_n\to y_n$? I know what $x_n\to y$ means, not $x_n\to y_n$. Thus, 1. is meaningful (and happens to be correct) while 2. and 3. do not even mean anything.